# How to delete nth element from a link list?

Tags: haskell

How to delete nth element from a link list?

```
import Data.List 

data LinkedList = LLEmpty  | LLNode Int LinkedList deriving (Eq, Show, Ord)
```

Inserting an integer at the n-th position

```
linkListInsertNPosition :: Int -> Int -> LinkedList -> LinkedList                       
linkListInsertNPosition pos val listL =
    let ninsertion = insertionN val (lengthL listL - pos) listL
        in ninsertion

insertionN :: Int -> Int -> LinkedList -> LinkedList           
insertionN val count listL =
    case listL of
        LLEmpty -> LLEmpty
        (LLNode a b) -> if (count <=0)
                            then LLNode val (LLNode a b)
                       else LLNode a (insertionN val (count - 1) b)
```

last,tail and head of link list

```
lastL :: LinkedList -> Int                             
lastL listL =
    case listL of
        LLNode a b -> a

tailL :: LinkedList -> LinkedList                   
tailL listL =
    case listL of
    LLEmpty -> LLEmpty
    LLNode a b -> b

headL :: LinkedList -> Int                   --100
headL listL =
case listL of 
    LLNode a LLEmpty -> a
    LLNode a b -> headL (tailL b)
```

Obtaining the length of a linked list

```
lengthL :: LinkedList -> Int                    
lengthL listL =
case listL of
    LLEmpty -> 0
    LLNode a b -> 1 + (lengthL (tailL listL))
```

I'm stucked on deleting nth element in a link list. Can anyone help me and suggest a way.
How to join the link list after the nth element is deleted? or i will need to do a new link list?

Comment: A Haskell list `[a]` is already a linked list, so is there a specific reason why you did not use `a` and defined your own (more verbose) one?

Comment: Furthermore I do not really get why you post all kinds of functions that can be performed on the linked list here. The one that seems the most relevant is inserting at the *n*-th position, so perhaps you can retain that one and rewrite it to delete a node instead.

Comment: I'm told to do that way. Okay i'll delete the other functions. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linked list `LList` is either `Empty` or contains a value and another linked list.

```
data LList a = Empty | Node a LList
```

This is probably easier if we define an operator (like `(:)` for the built-in `[]` linked-list)

```
data LList a = Empty | a :+: LList
--   much like:
-- data [a]  = []    | a :   [a]
```

Your lists are specifically `Int`s, so we can drop the polymorphism

```
data LList = Empty | Int :+: LList
  deriving (Eq, Show, Ord)

-- and, useful for testing:
fromList :: [Int] -> LList
fromList = foldr (:+:) Empty
```

---

Inserting after `n` is just pushing through the linked list `n` times and re-linking at that point.

```
import Data.Either (partitionEithers)
-- partitionEithers :: [Either a b] -> ([a], [b])

-- fun fact, I had to look this one up, but this is how haskell implements (++)
(|++|) :: LList -> LList -> LList
Empty    |++| ys    = ys
xs       |++| Empty = xs
(x:+:xs) |++| ys    = x :+: (xs |++| ys)

mySplitAt :: Int -> LList -> (LList, LList)
mySplitAt n = partitionEithers . map (go n) . zip [0..]
  where
  go n (i, x) | i < n     = Left x
              | otherwise = Right x

insertAfter :: Int -> Int -> LList -> LList
insertAfter n x xs = before |++| (x :+: after)
  where (before, after) = mySplitAt n xs
```

Which means naturally that deleting the nth value is just relinking after a specific node

```
delete :: Int -> LList -> LList
delete n xs = before |++| after
  where (before, _ :+: after) = mySplitAt n xs
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps this will give you some ideas

```
Prelude> let removeAt n = map snd . filter ((/=n) . fst) . zip [1..]
Prelude> removeAt 3 [1..10]
[1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

either you can count the position recursively, or add an index with `zip` and work on that index.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this.

```
removeNth :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
removeNth n ls = let (pref, suff) = splitAt n ls
                 in  pref ++ (tail suff)
```